# TLP overrides auto-suspend configuration

Tags: arch-linux, power-management, thinkpad

On my ThinkPad x201, I've been having problems where the computer will shutdown once it has been suspended to RAM, so I disabled the auto-suspend when the lid is closed by editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`:

```
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=None
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
```

This works fine, however, when running tlp, my computer starts to suspend again. I have looked through the arch wiki and [the documentation](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#startstop), but still haven't found a flag that controls this.

Is there any way to control tlp's override of the auto-suspend feature when laptop lids are closed?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it was `tp_smapi`'s fault! I uninstalled it, and I can successfully suspend to RAM (even with TLP)